# React social login issue with with google api error popup_closed_by_user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, react-hooks

Hi I am newbie in `react js`.
I have implemented react-social-login on google login. It is working fine fine on normal browser like google chrome normal browser, when it runs over in incognito mode of chrome or internet edge.

It displays error on console and doesn't redirect to home page:

[image]

Comment: what you wrote in the code, please share that. Give more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reported bug in that package repository. you can go through it for a solution.
https://github.com/deepakaggarwal7/react-social-login/issues/134
https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/issues/132#issuecomment-457056944